get a value of useState inside of listener
I want to display a list of coordinates that I got from click event on DIV. I want the listener works only when a button was clicked.
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const AppRestoration = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = useCallback((event) => {
    console.log(coordinates) // is empty array
    setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => [...prevCoordinates, event.clientX]
    );
  }, [setCoordinates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Coordinates:", ...coordinates); // When they update
  }, [coordinates]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        ici
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setActive((prev) => !prev)}>
        {active ? "clicked" : "not"}
      </button>
      <SecondComponent secondCParam={coordinates} />
    </div>
  );
};

const SecondComponent = ({ secondCParam }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {secondCParam.map((coord) => (
        <li key={crypto.randomUUID()}>{coord}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<AppRestoration />)


The problem is : in handleClick(event) I can not filter "coordinates", it is always an empty array. To refresh it, I have to click on the button, so handleClick one more time. How to avoid it?

try wrapping handleClick inside useCallback hook with corresponding dependencies of setClickCoord and coordinates. Does this help ?

@BorisBorais I'm not sure to understand you,
React.useCallback(()=> {
}, [setClickCoord, coordinates]), but if I put handleClick inside (), it changes nothing

FWIW just going to throw it out there that div elements are semantically non-interactive HTML elements. If you want to make them interactive then add the appropriate ARIA role, tab-index, and click/keyPress handlers.... or maybe just use a button element and apply CSS. ‍♂️

The issue you have here is a stale closure over the coordinates state in the callback handler. Use a functional state update so the setClickCoord updater function is accessing the current state and your issue disappears.

You seem to still be struggling with the Javascript closure issue. Can you [edit] to include a more complete and representative [mcve] of the actual code you are trying to use?

Why not add the click handler to the element, and do it the React way?
<div
  style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
  onClick={handleClick}
>

const handleClick = useCallback(({ clientX }) => {
  setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) =>
    !prevCoordinates.includes(clientX)
      ? [...prevCoordinates, clientX]
      : prevCoordinates
  );
}, [setCoordinates]);

Also, a state called state is ambiguous. You should rename it to a more appropriate name. For the time being, I named it active, since the button toggles.


const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const AppRestoration = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = useCallback((event) => {
    setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) =>
      !prevCoordinates.includes(event.clientX)
        ? [...prevCoordinates, event.clientX]
        : prevCoordinates
    );
  }, [setCoordinates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Coordinates:", ...coordinates); // When they update
  }, [coordinates]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        ici
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setActive((prev) => !prev)}>
        {active ? "clicked" : "not"}
      </button>
      <SecondComponent secondCParam={coordinates} />
    </div>
  );
};

const SecondComponent = ({ secondCParam }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {secondCParam.map((coord) => (
        <li key={crypto.randomUUID()}>{coord}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<AppRestoration />);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4rem !important; }
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




thank you for your solution, but before update my coordinates inside of handleClick, I want to check if this coordinate is already in my coordinates. so if I do this, my coordinates are empty :
const handleClick = useCallback(     (event) => {       if (coordinates.find(event.clientX)... // it gives an empty array coordinates       setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => [...prevCoordinates, event.clientX]);     },     [setCoordinates]   )

@MatveevAleksandr Do that check in the setCoordinates callback where you have access to the current state value, not outside it, e.g. setCoordinates(coordinates => condition ? nextCoordinates : coordinates). Also, the useCallback hook isn't helping you here.

@MatveevAleksandr I updated the setCoordinates call to check the prev value for the existence of the clientX value.

@DrewReese coordinates inside of setCoordinates(coordinates => condition ? nextCoordinates : coordinates) are empty array

@MatveevAleksandr It will be empty until you update it to a non-empty value.

@MatveevAleksandr what's wrong with the code above? It adds a new x-coordinate to the list upon click. After the coordinate list is updated, there is a separate effect to display the updated coordinate list. Do not try to access the actual coordinates state when trying to call setCoordinates. This is not the React way to do things.

You should avoid using native JS event listeners in React. Here is how you can refactor your code to achieve the same result with a React approach:
export function AppRestoration() {

  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [coordinates, setClickCoord] = useState<any[]>([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="alex" onClick={() => {
   if (state) setClickCoord(prevCoordinates => [...prevCoordinates, event.clientX]);
}} style={{ width: '200px', height: '200px', backgroundColor:'red' }}>ici</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>{state ? 'clicked' : 'not'}</button>
      <SecondComponent
        secondCParam={coordinates} />
    </div>
  )
}

However, if you want to experiment with event listeners and use this pattern anyway, you could refactor handleClick like so:
const handleClick = (event) => {
    // I need to get access to coordinates here (to filter them), but it is always an empty array
    setClickCoord(prevCoordinates => {
      console.log(prevCoordinates);
      return [...prevCoordinates, event.clientX]);
    });
  }

Since the list is updating but the console.log shows nothing, the issue might be that your console.log only displays the initial value of coordinates ([]).
I would strongly advise you to not use event listeners in React and to use refs when you need to interact with DOM elements (instead of using getElementById or querySelector).

the first snippet would work nice. But in second one it might fail due to stale reference
